# Linq to XML using Descendents and Where Clause

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <property>
         <propertydetails>
             <siteid>4</siteid>
         </propertydetails>
         <gallery>
              <image>
                  <imagesrc></imagesrc>
              </image>
          </gallery>
      </property>
 </root>
```

What I would like to do using LINQ to XML (C#) is ultimately get all the gallery images for a particular siteid. So, I'm guessing that it would be best to return the whole property element where the propertydetails/siteid is equal to a certain value.

I am thinking the following does not work because I'm trying to search for an element within the descendent and it's not a direct element. The siteid is below propertydetails but I want to access the whole property tag to get the gallery images.

```
     var properties = from property in root.Descendants("property")
             where (int)property.Element("siteid") == id
             select new PropertyModel
             {
                  SiteId = Convert.ToInt32(property.Element("siteid").Value),
                   Images = new List<string>(from gallery in property.Descendants("gallery")
                                              select gallery.Element("imagesrc").Value)
                             };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain it's an answer to the above, but it certainly is a solution. I am using the xsd converter to turn the xml to an xsd file and then convert the xsd file to a c# sharp class that can be used to load the xml and perform subsequent processing.